# Is there a better way to determine $E(X_{n+1}|X_{n})$ for this problem?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Suppose we have two boxes containing $M$ balls each. At each time increment, one ball is uniformly selected from each box, and then placed in the other one. If at time $0$ the first box contains $M$ white balls and the second one contains $M$ black balls, define $X_{n}$ to be the number of black balls inside the first box at time $n$.

I have already computed all the transition probabilities, but I'm now looking to determine $E(X_{n+1}|X_{n})$ for $n=0,1, \dots$ and then to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} E(X_{n}) = M/2$.

To do this, I've reasoned that for each time $n$, $X_{n}$ can at most be at state $M$. So I tried working out $$E(X_{n+1}|X_{n}=j)= \sum_{k=1}^{\max(n+1,M)} kP(X_{n+1} = k| X_{n} = j) $$

where $j \in \{0, \dots, \max(n,M)\}$. I don't think I need to do double summation since there's a lot of zero terms). That is, I can restrict attention to $j \in \{k-1, k, k+1\}$, but the problem is still messy. And things are complicated when $k \in \{0,M\}$.

There have been some difficulties working this out, so I'm here to ask if there's something more simple I should be doing? It seems like this path would get needlessly messy.

**Edit:** I could post the transition probabilities, if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's find this using identifier RVs. Let $I_{1\to2}$ be equal to 1 if the ball going from bin 1 to bin 2 is black at time $n+1$ and 0 otherwise. Similarly define $I_{2\to1}$. We now have
\begin{align*}
E[X_{n+1}|X_n]&=X_n - E[I_{1\to2}|X_n] + E[I_{2\to1}|X_n]\\
&=X_n-P[I_{1\to2}=1|X_n]+ P[I_{2\to1}=1|X_n]\\
&=X_n-\frac{X_n}{M}+\frac{M-X_n}{M}\\
&=X_n\left(1-\frac2M\right)+1.
\end{align*}
So 
$$
E[X_{n+1}]=E[E[X_{n+1}|X_n]]=E[X_n]\left(1-\frac2M\right)+1.
$$

By finding the limit of the recurrence $$a_{n+1}=a_n\left(1-\frac2M\right)+1,\quad a_0=0,$$ you should be able to prove $E[X_n]\to M/2$.

Answer (score 0):

$E(X_{n+1}|X_n=k)$ is a bit messy, but expand it out.  I got $k+1-2k/M$.
Rewrite it as $k=\frac M2+a$, and you should see the expectation gets closer to $M/2$ by a constant factor.